# Video file is hanging after concatenating video files and drawtext to output

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to concat 3 video files and add text to output using ffmpeg.
Each part is 10 sec long.

I've end up with this code:

```
ffmpeg -i output3.mp4 -i output2.mp4 -i output1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]; [0:v:0]drawtext=fontfile=tahoma.ttf:text=Sample text:fontcolor=white:fontsize=40:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.7:boxborderw=5:x=100:y=100" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

The result video has 30 seconds but it hangs after 1st part (10s). When I remove drawtext filter part (just concat), then video is fine, but without text...
Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i output3.mp4 -i output2.mp4 -i output1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]; [v]drawtext=fontfile=tahoma.ttf:text=Sample text:fontcolor=white:fontsize=40:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.7:boxborderw=5:x=100:y=100[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

Your existing syntax applied the text on top of the video stream of the first input file, instead of the resultant video from the concat filter.